# Doubts about best choices for a webserver

Tags: linux, mysql, web-server, scalability

I have this config.

- Quad core i7 930 (x64)
- 6gb ram

WEBSITE architecture

- php language for website
- mysql and it is possible the use of cassandra
- SSL protocol
- three hundred thousand visits (daily)

And i have this requisites:

```
 - linux server (i prefer a distro with GUI to install)
 - high scalability
 - Fast
 - something faster than apache ? (LiteSpeed ?, Nginx ?,  Cherokee ? )
```

My question is:

what is the most indicated distro (debian ?) and webserver ?

Is the hardware config enough ?, a ssd make difference in the performance ?

From what number daily visits makes sense an architecture distributed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the most indicated distro

Whatever you're most comfortable with.

> and webserver ?

Depends on what you're most comfortable with, what your environment will look like, and what your needs are.

> Is the hardware config enough ?

There is no possibly way for me or anyone else here to give an honest answer to this question.

> a ssd make difference in the performance ?

Depends on whether or not your application is IO-bound.

> From what number daily visits makes sense an architecture distributed?

It nearly **always** makes sense to engineer things to allow for scaling the application layer, the db layer, or both. It's usually recommended to start simple, though, and scale from there if you need it.

Comment: ok, i understand that the comfortable  aspect is important, but the learning factor is not a problem if i have a considerable performance gain. I read that LiteSpeed is 6 times faster than apache. It is a considerable difference.

Comment: As with any choice, there are always going to be pros and cons. LiteSpeed may indeed be faster than Apache for some workloads, but I guarantee that it is lacking much of the functionality that Apache has. For your application, that may not be a big deal. Also, LiteSpeed's install base (and therefore your support community) is *much* smaller than Apache's. When you're getting to learn a tech, it's best to stick with something you can easily get good help on.

Comment: ok, thanks for help, and sorry for the question, seems that was not well accepted.

Comment: @Fel - you're welcome. Don't let the fact that your question got closed discourage you from continuing to use the site. Just read the FAQ, and you'll see what type of questions are appropriate. In this case, you were asking very subjective questions, which would be impossible to give a real answer to.